# What is meromorphic differentials like on Riemann Sphere?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

There is a proposition that every meromorphic differential on Riemann Sphere (or $\mathbb{P}^1 = \mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$) can be written as $f dz$ where $f$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{P}^1$, and that $f dz$ is meromorphic if and only if $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and $z^2 f(z)$ tends to a finite limit as $z \rightarrow \infty$.

This is *Exercise 6.3.* on Page 178 of Frances Kirwan's *Complex algebraic curves*. I know how to prove the former half of the proposition (every meromorphic differential can be written as $f dz$),  but I cannot find a proof of **the second half**. In fact, I'm not sure whether the propostion is true, because I seem to find a meromorphic differential which is not holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ (e.g. $1/z$ $dz$).

Does anyone can answer my question?

Comment: Is it not a typo? Surely $fdz is *holomorphic* iff those conditions are satisfied.

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a typo in the original book. Additionally, it seems that there is no non-zero holomorphic differentials on $\mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: As you have observed there are meromorphic differentials on $\P^1$ which are not holomorphic on $\C$ (like $dz/z$). So it seems that there is a typo in the original. Also, you can probably prove that the statement is true after replacing meromorphic by holomorphic. Then, indeed, you can show that there are no non-zero functions satisfying that condition...

Comment: Maybe. Well anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh, I got it. The exercise following this one is "To deduce that there are no holomorphic differentials on $\mathbb{P}^1$", and this is just a proof of it (I know another proof previously, so I didn't get what the writer means). Well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The second half of the statment is not true, but if we replace "meromorphic" by **holomorphic**, it becomes a true proposition:

> $f(z)dz$ is **holomorphic** if and only if $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ and $z^2f(z)$ tends to a finite limit as $z \rightarrow \infty$.

This is easy to prove because $$f(z_1)dz_1=-f(1/z_2)/z_2^2 dz_2$$ when changing local coordinate, and $$\lim\limits_{z_1\to\infty}f(z_1)z_1^2 = \lim\limits_{z_2\to 0}f(1/z_2)/z_2^2$$

In fact, there is no non-zero holomorphic function $f(z)$ that satisfies the condition above, so there is no non-zero holomorphic differential on $\mathbb{P}^1$.